# Disabling Logs in Android using Proguard

Tags: android, logging, proguard, google-geocoder

i added proguard rule `-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {public *;}` so my release version have no logs. but after that a specific methode stoped working:

```
SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(PassagerActivity.this,
                        new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                            @Override public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {

                              //  Log.e("xxx",location.latitude + "/" +location.longitude);

                                map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(location.latitude, location.longitude, 0.0),
                                        Map.Animation.NONE);

                                currentloc = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                               // loadingDialog.stopLoadingDialog();
                                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                        
                                GeoCoderApi.getAdressfromLatLng(PassagerActivity.this , location ,new GeoCoderApi.AdressCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAdressAvailable(String adress) {

                                      //  Log.e("xxxadress",adress);
                                        addDepart.post(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                addDepart.setText(adress);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });    }}).start(); 
                            }
                        });
```

this methode get the lat and lng and get an adress from google GeoCoder.
when i remove the proguard rule everything works just fine . Dont even know how it s related. i tried it in 4 different devices.

**EDIT:**

*Here u can see that the map.center() works and i can get the localisation it s just the addDepart.setText() that doesnt work.*

[image: Activity after i removed the proguard rule]

[image: Activity before i removed the proguard rule]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using this

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  *;
}
```

did break my code because

> this rule says that anything public in android.util.Log and its
> superclasses has no side-effects. That include the synchronization
> methods defined on Object class. Because the single one super class of
> android.util.Log is java.lang.Object . And Object#notify is very much
> with side effects.

So be really careful with assumenosideeffectsand always think about specifying exact signatures because it affects the super classes as well.

and use this instead :

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  v(...);
  d(...);
  i(...);
  w(...);
  e(...);
  println(...);
}
```

[Source](https://medium.com/yazio-engineering/how-to-break-your-android-app-with-proguard-r8-6566bc387b63)